# linebreak in bibliography with url and date

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I have an issue with urls and urldate. The line is a little bit too long for one line, but I have no idea how to fix a manual linebreak in urldate.

I've had a look into the bbl-file, but the urldate-field consists of three fields (urlday, urlmonth and urlyear).

Do you have an idea how to fix this issue?

Edit: At first, I tried to use https:// instead of http:// for a simple solution, but that didn't work. That's why you see https:// on the screenshot.

Thank you,
S

Here is my biblatex-entry and the package definition:

```
@online{wiki-bogosort,
title = {Bogosort},
author = {Wikipedia},
citeseerurl = {http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort},
urldate = {2014-10-18},
url = {http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort},
}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric,
natbib=true,
hyperref=true,
backref=true,
]{biblatex}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Thank you for your answers, \raggedright may be an option.
Everything compiles fine, but the line with Bogosort is too long.

See:
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome, posting a minimal working example would be great, as we need to know the margins to reproduce this. Your best bet to avoid stuff like that in general would be typesetting the bibliogaphy `\raggedright`.

Comment: I have no problem whatsoever completing the code and compiling.

Comment: [creating a LaTeX minimal example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) and/or [Was ist ein vollständiges Minimalbeispiel?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/569/was-ist-ein-vollstandiges-minimalbeispiel-oder-kurz-vm-und-wie-erstelle-ich-dieses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}` before printing the bibliography, according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241355/65072).