# When line breaking goes wrong: does \hfuzz influence \emergencystretch

Tags: line-breaking

I read the excellent reply by David Carlisle on a [line breaking question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness). However, one question remained open for me.

Carlisle wrote:

> `\hfuzz` does not affect the typesetting in any way but just stops TeX complaining if the box is is only slightly over-full.

and

> [...] `\emergencystretch` does not change the setting of "good" paragraphs, it only changes the setting of paragraphs that would have produced over-full boxes.

Both options on their own are clear. Does `\hfuzz` only remove warnings from the stdout and log file or does it also prevent emergency stretching?

As an example assume `\emergencystretch = 1em`and `\hfuzz=5pt`. If an hbox were overfull by 3 pt would the whitespace still be stretched to avoid it? (If it were, the considerably increased whitespace between words might be worse than overrunning a paragraph by an amount which is under the threshold of the writer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `\hfuzz` doesn't affect the line breaking decisions.

TeX will use a sequence of line breaks so that no line is overfull/underfull, if it's able to find one. Otherwise it will use the sequence the least amount of demerits even if a line is overfull/underfull; the value of `\hfuzz` only affects the console/log output: if a line is overfull beyond `\hfuzz`, you'll be warned.

If I take Ulrike’s example and set `\tracingparagraphs=1`, the first two paragraphs show exactly the same trace:

```
@firstpass
@secondpass
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 blub xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
@ via @@0 b=* p=0 d=*
@@1: line 1.3 t=0 -> @@0
xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
@ via @@1 b=8 p=0 d=324
@@2: line 2.2 t=324 -> @@1
xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
@\par via @@2 b=0 p=-10000 d=*
@@3: line 3.2- t=324 -> @@2


Overfull \hbox (38.70877pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--8
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 blub xxxxxxx xxxxxxx
 []

@firstpass
@secondpass
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 blub xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
@ via @@0 b=* p=0 d=*
@@1: line 1.3 t=0 -> @@0
xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
@ via @@1 b=8 p=0 d=324
@@2: line 2.2 t=324 -> @@1
xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
@\par via @@2 b=0 p=-10000 d=*
@@3: line 3.2- t=324 -> @@2
```

The only difference is that no warning message is shown in the second case, where `\hfuzz` has been set to 40pt.

Now change the example to

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\textwidth=3cm

\tracingparagraphs=1

\begin{document}
blub xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx

\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
blub xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx

\hfuzz=40pt
blub xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx

\end{document}
```

The first paragraph will have a line which is overfull by 36.27544pt. The second and third paragraphs are typeset exactly in the same way, regardless of the changed value of `\hfuzz`, which would allow the third paragraph to be set alike the first one, if it affected the line breaking decision. Here's the log.

#### First paragraph

```
@firstpass
@secondpass
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 blub xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
@ via @@0 b=* p=0 d=*
@@1: line 1.3 t=0 -> @@0
xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
@ via @@1 b=8 p=0 d=324
@@2: line 2.2 t=324 -> @@1
xxxxxxx xxxxxxx 
@\par via @@2 b=0 p=-10000 d=*
@@3: line 3.2- t=324 -> @@2
```

#### Second paragraph

```
@firstpass
@secondpass
@emergencypass
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 blub 
@ via @@0 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@1: line 1.2 t=100 -> @@0
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
@ via @@1 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@2: line 2.2 t=200 -> @@1
xxxxxxx 
@ via @@2 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@3: line 3.2 t=300 -> @@2
xxxxxxx 
@ via @@2 b=0 p=0 d=100
@ via @@3 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@4: line 3.2 t=300 -> @@2
xxxxxxx 
@ via @@3 b=0 p=0 d=100
@ via @@4 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@5: line 4.2 t=400 -> @@4
xxxxxxx 
@\par via @@4 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@\par via @@5 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@6: line 4.2- t=400 -> @@4
```

#### Third paragraph

```
@firstpass
@secondpass
@emergencypass
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 blub 
@ via @@0 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@1: line 1.2 t=100 -> @@0
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
@ via @@1 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@2: line 2.2 t=200 -> @@1
xxxxxxx 
@ via @@2 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@3: line 3.2 t=300 -> @@2
xxxxxxx 
@ via @@2 b=0 p=0 d=100
@ via @@3 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@4: line 3.2 t=300 -> @@2
xxxxxxx 
@ via @@3 b=0 p=0 d=100
@ via @@4 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@5: line 4.2 t=400 -> @@4
xxxxxxx 
@\par via @@4 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@\par via @@5 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@6: line 4.2- t=400 -> @@4
```

#### Console output

```
Overfull \hbox (36.27544pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--8
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 blub xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--11
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 blub

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--11
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 13--14
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 blub

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 13--14
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it out:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\textwidth=3cm

\begin{document}
blub xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx

\hfuzz=40pt
blub xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx

\emergencystretch=1em
blub xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was an effective demonstration.. That's rather interesting, I did not expect that `hfuzz` and `emergencystretch` could be changed for parts of a document.

Comment: I normally use \emergencystretch only for one paragraph, or e.g. before the bibliography.

Comment: It is quite useful in paragraphs with a couple of those too-many-word-containing compounds.

Comment: I didn't mean that it is not useful, but I'm not using it for the complete document but enable it only for the paragraphs where it is really needed (after checking if a rewording or some additional hyphenation is possible).

Comment: Yes, and sorry, that I didn't mention that I completely concur. It is very useful for those paragraphs to obtuse to set properly. However, for then entire document the side-effect seem a bit too much.

Thanks for pointing that out (at what must be an early Saturday morning in Germany, thanks twice)