# Is it tolerable to force hyphenation in English one-syllable words in small layouts?

Tags: typography, hyphenation, microtype

I already know English language does not allow hyphenation of one-syllable words, that is why I am not asking this question on english.sx.

But I am facing a typesetting task (humanities) with a very small layout which cannot be changed, and with a font and font size that cannot be changed, too.

I have some occurences where one-syllable words, such as `thought`, overflow the margin, see second instance here:

[image]

I am already using [`microtype`](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype), which helps a little, but not enough.

My question is if it is typographically acceptable to force hyphenation in one-syllable words in rare circumstances?

Could I have that example as `thou-ght`?

It *is* wrong, but will it be tolerated by an English readership?

If not, what can be done to accomodate such a situation? What would a professional typesetter do?

Comment: This isn't really a TeX question, but I think the answer is unequivocally, no, it's never appropriate unless perhaps at a morpheme boundary. So 'thou-ght' would be completely wrong; maybe in a pinch you could get away with 'dog-s', but I don't think this would be much better.

Comment: Thank you. If not, how what can be done to accomodate such situation? What a professional typesetter would do?

Comment: The solution here (if you're not able to rewrite the text) would be use make the paragraph `\sloppy`.

Comment: Nice, that simple answer escaped me. That would suffice. If you would like to post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: There are some other options; a lot will depend on your actual example. See [What is the meaning of \fussy, \sloppy, \emergencystretch, \tolerance, \hbadness?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness)

Comment: Use `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` for the paragraph

Comment: Thank you for advice. I will definitely play more with microtype, too.

Comment: \sloppy or (perhaps better fro really short lines) `\raggedright`

Comment: I cannot comment about English readers (I am not), but I noticed that some people accept better a very bad inter-word spacing than a well-placed hyphen. Probably this is the side effect of be more used to word processor defaults and web pages than to real books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I am generating an answer based on the comments with some additions).

*My question is if it is typographically acceptable to force hyphenation in one-syllable words in rare circumstances?*

No.

*It is wrong, but will it be tolerated by an English readership?*

Probably not.

*If not, what can be done to accomodate such situation?*

Depends on the situation. Some suggestions:

- Use `\sloppy`, or `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` for the paragraph. However, as barbara beeton points out in a comment, the environment will isolate the text, which may not be what you want, and `\sloppy` may escape, and it is recommended not to use it for the whole document. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness) answer explains different options; `\emergencystretch` might help.
- Use `\raggedright` for really short lines. Raggedness tends to become a good option the shorter the lines are. If there are external requirements that forbids raggedness, you may have a chance in convincing the people responsible by showing them some really horrible examples to where this can lead to. [`ragged2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e), as Thérèse points out, gives a »nicer rag« and offers a few more possibilities. Some info [here.](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-2/making-type-choices/justified-vs-rag-right)
- Make full use of `microtype` wherever you can. Currently most options are available with `pdftex`. As you may have noticed, your first line is also overflowing, but much less. *Kerning* would have probably moved the ›,‹ closer to the ›y‹, and the ›o‹ closer to the ›N‹. Alas, some fonts don’t have kerning, but the situation is improving rapidly. Punctuation is tolerated to slightly slip into the margin. This is useful to know if one-syllable words are followed by some punctuation, e.g. with ›thought,‹. Also a feature in `microtype`.

Comment: Using the `sloppypar environment unambiguously isolates the affected text.  `\sloppy` is too likely to escape and affect the whole document.

Comment: The `ragged2e` package will give you a nicer rag.

Comment: I incorporated your information/suggestions into the answer.

Comment: You've interpreted my comment on `sloppypar` rather backwards.  I meant that the isolation is generally a good thing, because sloppiness, if applied generally, can have a detrimental effect on paragraphs that are quite satisfactorily set with no special treatment.  I don't think *anyone* wants that.