# Some page content goes beyond the page borders

Tags: margins, geometry

I'we created such file:

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
%\usepackage[showframe, margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \paragraph{Aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}

    Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.

    \url{http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_bbbbbbbbbb_cccccccccccccccc_ddddddddd_eeeeeeeee}

\end{document}
```

When I convert it to pdf with command `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "latex-experimenting".tex` (actually TeXstudio does that), I've got such a file:

[image: Misformatted file]

At first I supposed, that problem occurs only when I use package `geometry`, but I reproduced the problem without it.

I am not requiring those "fake words" to be hyphenated by parts, I would be satisfied, if they would just be moved to the next line, when needed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to here. TeX just can't hyphenate words like 'ddddddddddddddd'. The lines will work if you use real words instead. For URLs, you need to tell `hyperref` to split them at additional points, probably.

Comment: `\paragraph` is for a sub-heading, by the way.

Comment: Hello, @cfr!
When I comment usage of Geometry package, "word" "ccccccccccccc" is hyphenated!
Actually, I don't actually need those words to be hyphenated. If they would be placed on the next line, it would be fine too.

Comment: That's because it apparently knows how to hyphenate 'ccccccccccccc'. If you replace the 'ddddddddddddddd' with another 'ccccccccccccc', it'll hyphenate it with `geometry`, too. `geometry` isn't doing anything relevant here.

Comment: I've edited my question -- as I figured out, problem with line breaks occurs without `geometry` package too.

Comment: `\raggedright`? Hard to see how else you can do this if your document really needs such non-words.

Comment: You can play around with the parameters `\emergencystretch` and `\tolerance`. They influence how paragraphs are broken into lines. Basically this is what the commands `\sloppy` and `\fussy` do: `\sloppy` increases `\tolerance` and `\emergencystretch`. `\fussy` resets LaTeX's default values for these parameters. (`\hfuzz` and `\vfuzz` get changed also but this does not affect the look of the resulting .pdf file. This affects when TeX will print error-messages due to boxes being taken for overfull.)  [This might be of interest.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241355)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play around with the parameters `\emergencystretch` and `\tolerance`. They influence how paragraphs are broken into lines.

Basically this is what the commands `\sloppy` and `\fussy` do:
`\sloppy` increases `\tolerance` and `\emergencystretch`.
`\fussy` resets LaTeX's default values for these parameters.
(`\hfuzz` and `\vfuzz` get changed also but this does not affect the look of the resulting .pdf file. This affects when TeX will print error-messages due to boxes being taken for overfull.)

[These explanations by David Carlisle might be of interest.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241355)

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
%\usepackage[showframe, margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\avoidhyphens{%
  \emergencystretch\hsize
  \tolerance 200%
  \hfuzz .1\p@
  \vfuzz\hfuzz
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \hrule height 0pt width 0pt depth 0pt
    \kern-1in
    \kern-\topmargin
    \kern-\headheight
    \kern-\headsep
    %\kern-\topskip
    \vfill\verb|\fussy| is default:\vfill

    % The sectionng command "\paragraph" creates a vertical gap of 3.25ex with report. Let's remove that:
    \kern-3.25ex
    \paragraph{Aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}

    Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.

    \url{http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_bbbbbbbbbb_cccccccccccccccc_ddddddddd_eeeeeeeee}

    \vfill\verb|\avoidhyphens|:\vfill

    \avoidhyphens
    \kern-3.25ex
    \paragraph{Aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}

    Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.

    \url{http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_bbbbbbbbbb_cccccccccccccccc_ddddddddd_eeeeeeeee}

    \vfill\verb|\sloppy|:\vfill

    \sloppy
    \kern-3.25ex
    \paragraph{Aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}

    Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.

    \url{http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_bbbbbbbbbb_cccccccccccccccc_ddddddddd_eeeeeeeee}

    \vfill\verb|\fussy|:\vfill

    \fussy
    \kern-3.25ex
    \paragraph{Aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}

    Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.

    \url{http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_bbbbbbbbbb_cccccccccccccccc_ddddddddd_eeeeeeeee}

    \vfill\verb|\raggedright|:\vfill

    \begingroup\raggedright
    \kern-3.25ex
    \paragraph{Aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}

    Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.

    \url{http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_bbbbbbbbbb_cccccccccccccccc_ddddddddd_eeeeeeeee}

    \endgroup
    \vfill

\end{document}
```

[image]