# How to Allow Hyphenation in the Index While Forbidding It in the Rest of the Document

Tags: indexing, hyphenation, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % To prevent hyphenation
\begin{document}
\large
\lipsum[13]\index{HEADING@\textbf{\textit{HEADING}}! \lipsum[3]}
               
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index:

[image]

I have prevented hyphenation in the document by inserting `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` into the preamble; however, I would like to permit hyphenation in the Index.

QUESTION: Is it possible to permit hyphenation in the Index while simultaneously precluding it from occurring in the rest of the document? If so, how may I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the `hyphenpenalty` before the index:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % To prevent hyphenation
\begin{document}
\large
\lipsum[13]\index{HEADING@\textbf{\textit{HEADING}}! \lipsum[3]}
               
\hyphenpenalty=1000
\hbadness=1000
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. I tried running it without the `\hbadness=1000` and hyphenation occurred in the index, as I wanted. Would you tell me what this command does and why it might be needed? Thank you again.

Comment: `\hbadness` is not really needed, it's just helpful to report overfull boxes in the logs. You can read some useful info here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness/241355