# math mode $$ makes line too long inside itemize environment

Tags: math-mode, itemize

I have a list of items as follows:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item define \textit{N} to be the largest non-negative integer such that $k\times 4^{H-1}<max(f(X(t);4,3), f(X(t);5,7))$. If $f(X(t);0,-1)>k\times 4^{H-1}$ and blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla.
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

The problem is that the first line is too long (see picture=. How can I make the expression inside the math mode naturally go into the next line as if it was text?

My preamble

```
%\UseRawInputEncoding
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\section}
% {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
% \usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\subsection}
% {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\newcommand*{\defeq}{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape,url}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},labelsep=colon,justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{ \arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=0.9in, right=0.9in]{geometry}
\topmargin -1.5cm
\oddsidemargin -0.04cm
\evensidemargin -0.04cm
\textwidth 16.59cm
\textheight 21.94cm
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\newcommand\cites[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s\ (\citeyear{#1})}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{mathptmx,siunitx}
%\sisetup{input-symbols = {()},  % do not treat "(" and ")" in any special way
  %       group-digits  = false} % no grouping of digits
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\setlength{\footskip}{65pt}
\onehalfspacing
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{xr}
%\externaldocument[SND-]{NetworkDescription}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setappendix}{Appendix~\thechapter:~}
\newcommand{\setchapter}{\thechapter~}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\LARGE}{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{appendices}=0
    \setappendix
  \else
    \setchapter
  \fi}{0em}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\LARGE}{\fontsize{16}{17}\selectfont}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Latex does not automatically allow line breaks after comma in math. You can use say `,\allowbreak` and similar in certain places to give some breaking possibilities for the algorithm

Comment: using your code fragment in standard `article` document, i.e.: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item define $N$ to be the largest non-negative integer such that $k\times 4^{H-1}<\max(f(X(t);4,3), f(X(t);5,7))$. If $f(X(t);0,-1)>k\times 4^{H-1}$ and bla bla bla blabla bla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blblabla blablabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla blablabla bla bla bla blablabla.
\end{itemize}
 \end{document}` doesn't reproduce your problem. Please extent it complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example).

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. i added the info. Should work now.

Comment: @ \allowbreak works. is there another way of doing this (more general and not involving me deciding manually on the break location)?

Comment: Please make your document example minimal. Remove from preamble all what is not related to your problem. BTW, your preamble is a mess. Remove all duplicates and and reconsider whether you need all these packages ...

Comment: I don't know of any "automatic" solution that you are looking for.  Allowing a break after every comma is unsatisfactory; the decision (at present) is really best made by a human.  One approach is to make this equation an unnumbered display; that is what might be chosen by a trained copyeditor.  Otherwise, `\allowbreak` is really the best available approach.

Comment: What about using displayed math? "...define $N$ to be the  non-negative integer such that \[ k\times 4^{H-1}<max(f(X(t);4,3), f(X(t);5,7)). \] If ..."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rephrasing the sentence and offer the following example for your reference.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item define $k\times 4^{N-1}<\max(f(X(t);4,3), f(X(t);5,7))$ with \textit{N} being the largest non-negative integer. If $f(X(t);0,-1)>k\times 4^{H-1}$ and \ldots
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful, but not the general solution I am looking for.

Comment: You are welcome. I've tried to look for an improved solution for you and find \sloppy could also work in your case. ( I am not sure whether it is also recommended.) I hope [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness/241355) might be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your lengthy preamble to what I believe is the bare minimum needed to reproduce the formating issue you're looking to fix.

Basically, TeX does not like to allow line breaks in inline math, including right after commas. To enable a line break at a specific point, insert an `\allowbreak` directive as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\textwidth 16.59cm
\oddsidemargin -0.04cm
\evensidemargin -0.04cm
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Define $N$ to be the largest non-negative integer such that 
$k\times 4^{H-1}<\max(f(X(t);4,3), f(X(t);5,7))$. 
If $f(X(t);0,-1)>k\times 4^{H-1}$ and blablabla 
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla.

\item Define $N$ to be the largest non-negative integer such that 
$k\times 4^{H-1}<\max(f(X(t);4,3),\allowbreak f(X(t);5,7))$. 
If $f(X(t);0,-1)>k\times 4^{H-1}$ and blablabla 
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```