# "Underfull" or "Loose" box in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, badness

When badness exceeds `\hbadness`, there should be `Underfull`. When badness exceeds `\tolerance`, there should be `Overfull`.  Origin `story.tex` file is

```
\hrule
\vskip 1in
\centerline{\bf A SHORT STORY}
\vskip 6pt
\centerline{\sl by A. U. Thor}
\vskip .5cm
Once upon a time, in a distant
   galaxy called \"O\"o\c c,
there lived a computer
named R.~J. Drofnats.

Mr.~Drofnats---or ``R. J.,'' as
he preferred to be called---% error has been fixed!
was happiest when he was at work
typesetting beautiful documents.
\vskip 1in
\hrule
\vfill\eject
```

After `tex` command, `\hsize=1.5in \tolerance=10000\raggedright\hbadness=-1 \input story` was input, then `\end`, but the log file showed

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 230) in paragraph at lines 7--11
\tenrm in a dis-tant galaxy 

\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x108.405, glue set 1.3203
.\tenrm i
.\tenrm n
.\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
.\tenrm a
.\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33298
.etc.


Loose \hbox (badness 15) in paragraph at lines 7--11
\tenrm called []O^^?o^^Xc, there lived 

\hbox(9.20636+1.94444)x108.405, glue set 0.53001
.\tenrm c
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm e
.etc.
```

The code above is only a part of all. As `\hbadness=-1`, so there should be `Underfull` every line, but why are there `Loose` and what does `Loose` mean here?

Comment: your initial description is wrong. `\hbadness` does not affect whether or not a box is underfull, just whether there is a warning in the log.  `\tolerance` is unrelated to overfull boxes it is a limit on the total badness in a paragraph, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness/241355#241355

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. What I wanted to say is the `\hbadness` affects the `Underfull` in the log file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you state `\hbadness=-1` is responsible for the classifications
*underfull* and *loose*. An hbox is underfull if the glue stretches and the
badness is 100 or more. If the glue stretches and the badness is less
than 100 TeX calls the hbox loose.

If the glue shrinks TeX distinguishes between *overfull* and *tight*.

See page 302 of The TeXbook.

---

The classification occurs when TeX takes lists and packs them into
boxes: A horizontal lists is transformed into an hbox and a vertical
list into a vbox.

The badness of the constructed hbox is computed. If it is larger than
`\hbadness` TeX writes a message to the log file based on a comparison
against the hard-coded value 100; the message depends of the way how
the glue has to be changed.

If the glue has to stretch it writes:
If the badness is larger than 100 *underfull*, otherwise *loose*.

If the glue shrinks it writes:
If the badness is larger than 100 *overfull*, otherwise *tight*.

(A similar thing is done for vboxes and the parameter `\vbadness`.)

A second classification occurs with the line breaking
algorithm. During this procedure every line is assigned a fitness
class based on its badness and the change of the glue, i.e, if it
stretches or shrinks: tight, decent, loose, very loose.

A line with badness larger than 12 and glue that shrinks is *tight*;
with glue that stretches and a badness larger than 99 the line is
called *very loose*, with badness larger than 12 and less than 100
*loose*. A *decent* line has a badness less than 13 and its glue might
stretch or shrink or be kept at the natural width.

Therefore the words 'tight' and 'loose' are used in two different
contexts. A line with fitness class *decent* or *tight* might be tight
or overfull for the packaging; a line with fitness class *decent*,
*loose*, or *very loose* loose or underfull.

Comment: I have set `\badness=-1`, so when badness is more than -1, there should be `underfull`, but why did you say **An hbox is underfull if the glue stretches and the badness is 100 or more**? I once think 100 is the the default value here, but `hbadness=-1` will reset it.

Comment: @Y.zeng no, `\hbadness` has no effect on tex's output, it just affects when boxes are reported in the log. loose is always badness between 13 and 100

Comment: @DavidCarlisle May you tell why is there a 13 here? I have never defined it.

Comment: @Y.zeng it is not something you can define: it is built in to tex see the texbook on the page in Udo's answer. 13 happens to be the badness that means that glue is stretched by 50% of its stretch value (13 is approx 0.5^3*100)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle On that page and the answer of  Udo, only when badness is located between `\hbadness` and 100, it is loose, which has nothing to do with 13.

Comment: @Y.zeng oh whatver page chapter 14 \ddanger A line whose badness is 13 or more has a glue set ratio exceeding
50\%. We call such a line tight if its glue had to shrink,
loose if its glue had to stretch, and {very loose}
if it had to stretch so much that the badness is 100 or more. But if the
badness is 12 or less we say that the line is {\sl ^{decent}}. Two
adjacent lines are said to be {\sl {visually incompatible}\/} if their
classifications are not adjacent, i.e., if a tight line is next to a
loose or very loose line, or if a decent line is next to a very loose one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle We do not look at the _fitness classes_ of the line breaking
algorithm, which are tight, decent for lines with shrinking glue and
decent, loose, and very loose for lines with stretching glue. The
distinction about tight and decent and about loose and decent is that
the badness for tight and loose is 13 or larger. A line is very loose
if the badness is 100 or more. See §§852 and 853 in the code (Vol.B).

But the question is about the classification during the _packaging_. In the program (Vol.B) it's described in §660.

Comment: @UdoWermuth yes but I think the paragraph I quote is the only one that says why it is 13

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes your explanation of 13 is right but here we talk about a different classification in which 13 has no relevance.

Comment: @Y.zeng The 100 is a hard coded value in the program and thus independent of any parameter like \pretolerance, \tolerance, or \hbadness. See §660 of the program.

Comment: @UdoWermuth  What do you mean of §660?

Comment: @UdoWermuth If 13 is right, why have the `\hbadness=-1` here? What is its function?

Comment: @Y.zeng The whole program code of TeX is written in WEB that comes in sections. The book _TeX: The program_ that is Volume B in the _Computers&Typesetting_ series (Vol. A is _The TeXbook_) numbers these sections. §660 stands for section 660 of the WEB program.

Comment: @Y.zeng 13 belongs to a different classification: the socalled _fitness classes_ of the line breaking algorithm. They have nothing to do with the `\hbadness`. The program just uses _tight_ and _loose_ at two different places for two different things.

Comment: @Y.zeng The fitness classes are used to assign demerits during the line breaking as @DavidCarlisle points out. The `\hbadness` is a parameter to give information about the packaging und informs the user only through the log.

Comment: @UdoWermuth What is the difference between `\hbadness=-1` and `\hbadness=12`?

Comment: @Y.zeng The first value logs every loose line but the second only those that have a badness above 12; same for tight lines.

Comment: @UdoWermuth How do you tell tight and loose, by `\hbadness`?

Comment: @Y.zeng You see it in the log. `\hbadness` works for both and you cannot split the logging.