# Add spaces between letters of a word

Tags: spacing, kerning, white-space, underfull

In xelatex or lualatex, how can I get pararaphs to stretch words with tiny spaces within words as the last resort of typesetting?  It seems that everyone just wants tiny little hspace of fixed size between capital letters, but I want a space like `0em plus 0.05em` within each word - but I still need hyphenation to work, and I want normal kerning and ligatures when the stretch within the word is zero!

In the example, you'll see that for the underfull hbox of the first line, the spaces are as large as they can get, and the words start getting spaced out.  In the same paragraph, the word appears again, with regular spacing.  And the ligature for "fl" in "flesh" is present.

[image: Here's what I need to do]

I thought that TeX did this by default!

Here's latex failing at it:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
\rightskip=0.65\linewidth
23\hspace{1ex}And Abraham took Ishmael his son, and all that
were born in his house, and all that were bought with his 
money, every male among the men of Abraham's house; and 
circumcised the flesh of their foreskin in the selfsame day,
as God had said unto him.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you can use `\sloppy` or `\emergencystretch`, but better don't do it for a full document, only for bad paragraphs, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241355/2388. microtype often improves paragraphs too.

Comment: Note: [`microtype`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) activates font expansion by default. You can deactivate it, if you don't want it. Tracking (adding small spaces in words) can be activated with option `tracking`. All features depend on the engine (and output mode). XeLaTeX support it not the best, but some features are also available using `fontspec` instead. See the user manuals for more information.

Answer (score 3):

This is only to complete the excellent answers of cabohah (+1).

With xelatex you can use also some like  `\usepackage[shrink=20, stretch=30]{microtype}` which could be a solution while you maintain these parameters in reasonably low values (he effect  should be hardly noticed, or better not noticed at all).

---

[image: mwe]

---

But to answer exactly to your question  (add space between letters) you can  also set a some value to the option `letterspace`, for instance, `letterspace=150` and then type `\textls{Abraham}`:

---

[image: mwe]

---

(the value of 150 is deliberately exaggerated to see easily the effect. In this case, really  `letterspace=2` is enough).

Comment: Thank you for the flowers.

Comment: Okay, this is fun, but it's not really what I need:
`\usepackage[shrink=20, stretch=30]{microtype}` stretches the letters themselves, but doesn't act on the spaces between the letters.  I want to adjust the spacing between the letters, not the stretch of the letters themselves.  Some other random text formatting system has got it right ...

Comment: @TadPole So you want the `tracking` or `kerning` option of `microtype`. These are only available with LuaLaTeX or PDFLaTeX, but not with XeLaTeX (see my answer). Adjusting the `shrink` and `stretch` value is the best, you can do using `microtype` with XeLaTeX, if you don't want letterspacing (which is also also shown in Fran's answer). BTW: Using any kind of letter spacing for justifying text is very controversial. Several typographers vote against.

Answer (score 2):

Following works with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\rightskip=0.65\linewidth
\emergencystretch=1pt
23\enspace And Abraham took Ishmael his son, and all that
were born in his house, and all that were bought with his 
money, every male among the men of Abraham's house; and 
circumcised the flesh of their foreskin in the selfsame day,
as God had said unto him.
\end{document}
```

[image: with pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX]

With XeLaTeX the `tracking` feature is not available. Therefore you have to increase the `\emergencystretch` value:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\rightskip=0.65\linewidth
\emergencystretch=1em
23\enspace And Abraham took Ishmael his son, and all that
were born in his house, and all that were bought with his 
money, every male among the men of Abraham's house; and 
circumcised the flesh of their foreskin in the selfsame day,
as God had said unto him.
\end{document}
```

[image: xelatex + emergencystretch]

or have to use something like `sloppypar`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\rightskip=0.65\linewidth
\begin{sloppypar}
23\enspace And Abraham took Ishmael his son, and all that
were born in his house, and all that were bought with his 
money, every male among the men of Abraham's house; and 
circumcised the flesh of their foreskin in the selfsame day,
as God had said unto him.
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image: xelatex + sloppypar]

For more information about the features and which engine they need, please see the [`microtype`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) user manual. You will find there also a note about using `fontspec`'s `LetterSpace` (as a replacement of `tracking`) with XeLaTeX.